# How to update product image using polymorphic relaitonship

Tags: laravel, image, polymorphism, crud

This is my update method. I'm using simple polymorphic relation `morphTo()` and `morphOne()`. I'm having trouble in updating `Product` model.

```php
public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
{
    $product->name = $request->name;
    $product->price = $request->price;
    $product->discount = $request->discount;
    $product->category_id = $request->category;
    $product->brand_id = $request->brand;
    $product->is_active = $request->is_active;

    if($request->hasFile('url')) {
        $image = $request->file('url');
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move(public_path('storage/products'), $filename);
        $product->image->url = $request->file('url')->getClientOriginalName();
        // dd($product->image->url);
    }

    $product->save();
```

Comment: What is the error you encounter?

Comment: No error is shown. rest of the fields are updated but product image is not updated

Comment: And is `$request->hasFile('url')` `true`?

Comment: Yes it's true 'url' this is my images table     
           Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('url');
            $table->bigInteger('imageable_id');
            $table->string('imageable_type');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }